# Last generalized curvature zero for a hyper-planar curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

Serret-Frenet frame has been generalized to curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to enquire about what happens to the generalized curvatures if the curve belongs to one or more planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is the last (the (n-1)th) generalized curvature zero when the curve lies only on the (n-1)-dimensional plane (also called the hyper-plane)? If it lies on an (n-2)-dimensional plane, then the (n-2)th curvature zero and (n-1)th becomes undefined and so on? This is what happens in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes. Think of what a second derivative does to a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you suggest me a reference where I can get a proof?

Comment: Look here! http://academic.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/N-dimensional%20Frenet-Serret.pdf